# WPF falls into infinite loop when UseLayoutRounding="True"

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2010, xaml, .net-4.0

I've faced with a problem reproduced on .NET 4.0 when `UIElement.UseLayoutRounding="True"` and `TextBoxBase.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"` are set together.
The issue is reproduced only on Windows Classic theme (tested on Windows 7 and XP).

When the window is loaded, WPF shows and then hides vertical scroll bar on the TextBlock in infinite loop so that UI becomes unusable.

Markup is completely simple:

`App.xaml`:

```
<Application x:Class="PhysioControl.CodeStat.UI.Reviewer.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             StartupUri="MainWindowView.xaml"/>
```

`MainWindowView.xaml`:

```
<Window xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        UseLayoutRounding="True">
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBox VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Does anyone have any ideas of ways to avoid this?

Comment: Is 'Auto' setting for the VerticalScrollBarVisibility required? Can you set it always visible so that the loop does not occur?

Comment: The problem is that we have about 15K lines of XAML and it would take a lot of time to analyze and update each VerticalScrollBarVisibility. Also I'm not sure that this problem would not appear under other circumstances.

Comment: Maybe you should report this to Microsoft as a bug? You can do that at [Microsoft Connect](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/).

Comment: It seems that there is no bug reporting for for VS2010 and .NET 4.0.

Comment: I tested this using the code provided and Windows Classic theme on Windows 7 and it seems to work fine

Comment: It is reproducible, interesting bug... and it can be solved by setting the Height of TextBox explicitly, however, you have to check each VerticalScrollBarVisibility so it is probably not practical.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's something very funky going on in TextBoxView, the Reference Source for .NET 4.5 documents bug number 1766924 with a patch that disables background layout calculation for VerticalScrollBarVisibility=Auto.  Quoting:

```
        // Workaround for bug 1766924.
        // When VerticalScrollBarVisiblity == Auto, there's a problem with
        // our interaction with ScrollViewer.  Disable background layout to
        // mitigate the problem until we can take a real fix in v.next.
        //
```

This appears to be connected to this [feedback article](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/514011/wpf-scrollviewer-enters-infinite-measure-arrange-loop-in-a-certain-scenario) that describes your exact observation.

Known problem in .NET 4.0, fixed in 4.5.  Ask the users that suffer from this problem to install .NET 4.5 on their machine.  Note the workaround proposed by rfboilers if you need to keep XP users happy.

Comment: Unfortunately my app still has ~20% XP users. So I have to please them too. I'll try the workaround and see if it will work for those users who experienced problems. Thank you for sharing this info.

Comment: The workaround does not help :(
It seems I'll have to stick to always visible scroll bars until all users will use Vista+ and I will be able to require .NET 4.5

Answer (score -1):

It might be due to the Stackpanel. Scroll viewer will lost it visualization when it is inside a stackpanel.

Answer (score -1):

have you done a "clean project" or "clean solution" in visual studio?
sometimes something in the builds gets messed up